# New WIndows 2008 SP1 with SQL Server 2005 SP4 : unable to run this stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
use counts

select * 
from tools..create_output 'week16_em_final','counts',',opt_in,email,ip,sourceur','\\Sqlsrvr\f\Orders\misc\EliteMate\'
```

All I'm trying to do is export some data from one of our databases.

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'week16_em_final'.

Any idea why it wouldn't gather the data and export this small file?

Thanks for any and all help, I'm a newbie to SQL, so, sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if you have Import and Export Wizard:

[image]

[image]

You can enter your password if you choose `SQL Server Authentication` option also choose your `Server name` to a `Source Server` then `Database'

[image]

You can enter your password if you choose `SQL Server Authentication` option also choose your `Server name` to a `Destination Server` then Choose then `Database'

[image]
[image]

You can click edit mappings as an option.

[image]

Click `Next` or `Finish` Button

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using very **unsupported** software. You mention stored procedure - which we must guess is named create_output. If that is true, you can't use this syntax. You execute a stored procedure, you don't select from it. Example:

```
execute tools.dbo.create_output 'week16_em_final', 'counts',',opt_in,email,ip,sourceur','\\Sqlsrvr\f\Orders\misc\EliteMate\'
```

Note that I added the schema name (assumed to be dbo) - don't start bad habits. However, that string of parameters looks very strange as you formatted it so there will likely be other errors as well. If this is your first attempt, you should ask a colleague for help.